# how to use left join and group by in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, left-join

table in database

```
table 1
----------
id  name
----------
1   A
----------
2   B
----------


table 2
----------
id  order
----------
1   burger
1   cake          <----  I want to get the last data per ID
2   soda 
2   coffee        <-----  



RESULT
----------
id  name   order
----------
1    A     cake
2    b     coffee

TEST
----------
 1    A     burger
 1    A     cake
 2    b     soda
 2    b     coffee
```

I want to display data in table like in "RESULT" but I'm getting error..
It display like in "TEST"
 pls help

> testController.php
>
> $disp = DB::table('table1')
>       ->leftjoin('table2','table1.id','=','table2.id')
>       ->select('table1.*','table2.
>   *
>
> ')
>
> ->get();
>
> return  $disp;

Comment: "I'm getting error" please edit your question and include the error

Comment: I want to display the latest data

Comment: the result one? or the test one.

Comment: I want to display it like in Result..

Comment: in table2, if id = 1, order value has two value, you want the last one?

Comment: Yes the latest data inserted in table 2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $res = DB::table('table2')->join('table1','table2.id','=','table1.id')->select('table1.name','table2.*')->get();
    $result = $res->toArray();
    $result = array_reverse($result);
    $output = [];
    foreach($result as $re)
    {
        // dd($re);
        if(!array_key_exists($re->id,$output))
        {
            $output[$re->id] = [
                'id'   => $re->id,
                'order' => $re->order,
                'name' => $re->name
            ];
        }
    }
    dd(array_reverse($output));
```

Output will be

```
 [
  0 => [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "A"
    "order" => "Cake"
 ]
 1 => [
   "id" => 2
   "name" => "B"
   "order" => "Coffee"
]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leftJoin() function like this.

```
DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2','table1.id','=','table2.id')->select(DB::raw('table1.*, table2.*'))->groupBy('table1.id')->get();
```

Comment: It gives error "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Answer (score 0):

```
$disp = DB::table('table1')
  ->leftjoin('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')-> groupBy('table1.name')->get();
return $disp;
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation at what your code does or how it helps to solve the OP's problem

Comment: I want to select only the last data inserted in table 2 and join the name in table 1 like in "RESULT"   I want to display it like that but I don't know how do it, I dont know what sql I should use to display like in e.g "RESULT"

Answer (score 0):

use inner join

```
DB::table('table1')->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')->groupBy('table1.id')->get();
```

Comment: Could you provide a little explanation as to what the inner join is using? Or perhaps link to an inner join answer?

Comment: It will return first matching entry, not the last one.It will return `burger and soda`.he needs `cake and coffee` in output.